# Computing the covariance of the truncated normal distribution

Tags: r, normal-distribution, python, covariance, moments

In the paper [On Moments of Folded and Truncated Multivariate Normal Distributions](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2748900) on page 17, one can find the explicit expression for low order moments of the truncated multivariate normal distribution with $X \mid X > \alpha$. However, I do not get the right results when comparing it to some code in Python and R.

Let $\mu = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$ be the mean, $\Sigma = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0.1\\0.1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ the covariance and $\alpha = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$ the truncation points.

The mean of the univariate truncated normal is here

$$E[X_i] = \mu + \sigma\frac{\phi(\frac{-\mu}{\sigma})}{\Phi(\frac{\mu}{\sigma})} = \frac{\phi(0)}{\Phi(0)}$$

Using the formula from the paper while setting $\mu_i = 0$ and $\alpha_i = 0$ yields

$$E[X_iX_j] = \rho_{ij} + \frac{(1 - \rho_{ij}^2)\phi_2(0, 0 ;  0, \rho_{ij})}{\Phi_2(0, 0 ; 0, \rho_{ij})}$$

where $\rho_{ij} = \frac{0.1}{1}$ is the correlation coefficient, $\phi_2$ is the bivariate PDF and $\Phi_2$ the bivariate CDF.

Then the covariance of $X_1$ and $X_2$ is

\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(X_1, X_2) &= E[X_1X_2] - E[X_1]E[X_2]\\
      &= E[X_1X_2] - \left(\frac{\phi(0)}{\Phi(0)}\right)^2
\end{align}

```
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn

E_X_i = (norm.pdf(0)/norm.cdf(0))
print(E_X_i) # result = 0.7978845608028654
E_X_i_X_j = 0.1 + (1 - 0.1 ** 2) * mvn.pdf(0, mean=0, cov=0.1)/mvn.cdf(0, mean=0, cov=0.1)
cov = E_X_i_X_j - E_X_i ** 2
print(cov) # result = 1.9612814244323769
```

This result is wrong because in R the library [tmvtnorm](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2010/RJ-2010-005/RJ-2010-005.pdf) outputs:

```
install.packages("tmvtnorm")
library(tmvtnorm)

mtmvnorm(mean=c(0, 0), sigma=matrix(c(1, 0.1, 0.1, 1), 2, 2), lower=c(0, 0), upper=c(Inf, Inf))
$tmean
[1] 0.8250601 0.8250601

$tvar
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] 0.37882152 0.01473302
[2,] 0.01473302 0.37882152
```

The right answer is $\text{Cov}(X_i, X_j) = 0.01473302$. Also $E[X_i] = 0.8250601$ is slightly off (but numerical stability could be the issue).

Furthermore, I tried integrating the truncated distribution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143388/integrating-multivariate-normal-in-python-r), but with different results.

Where lies the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me some time, but I found the solution.

1. tmvtnorm is actually numerical stable. I just did not consider that $\mu_i$ also changes in the bivariate case. For $\mu = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$, $\Sigma_{ii} = 1$ and $X_i \mid X_i > 0$, the new $\mu$ is:

$$\mu_i = \frac{\rho\phi(0)\Phi(0) + \phi(0)\Phi(0)}{\Phi_2(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T; \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T, \Sigma)}$$

2. I did not enter the parameters correctly. It should be:

```
mvn.cdf(np.array([0, 0]), mean=np.array([0, 0]), cov=np.array([[1, 0.1], [0.1, 1]]))
```

3. The formula in the paper contains typos. For the case $\mu = \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T$, $\Sigma_{ii} = 1$ and $X_i \mid X_i > 0$, the formula should be:

$$E[X_iX_j] = \rho_{ij} + \frac{\sqrt{1 - \rho_{ij}^2}\phi^2(0)}{\Phi_2(\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T; \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0\end{bmatrix}^T, \Sigma)}$$

Then the corrected code is:

```
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal as mvn
import numpy as np

E_X_i = (0.1 * norm.pdf(0) * norm.cdf(0) + norm.pdf(0) * norm.cdf(0))/mvn.cdf(np.array([0, 0]), mean=np.array([0, 0]), cov=np.array([[1, 0.1], [0.1, 1]]))
print(E_X_i) # result = 0.8250601203844766
E_X_i_X_j = 0.1 + norm.pdf(0) ** 2 * np.sqrt(1 - 0.1 ** 2) / mvn.cdf(np.array([0, 0]), mean=np.array([0, 0]), cov=np.array([[1, 0.1], [0.1, 1]]))
cov = E_X_i_X_j - E_X_i ** 2
print(cov) # result = 0.014733023153836067
```

This result is like tmvtnorm `0.01473302`. Hence, my result is correct.